# Currently unable to display svg images from API in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, svg

Issue that I am currently having is displaying the svg images I am getting from an API for countries. Right now they are showing up as empty divs in the HTML and no errors. I am also using the ReactSVG package and still no luck.

Here below is the Home component which is making the API call and the Card component that fed the content:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import CardComponent from '../components/Card';

const baseURL = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all';

const Home = () => {
    const [ countries, setCountries ] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('hello')
        axios.get(baseURL).then((res) => {
            setCountries(res.data);
        })
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    {countries && (
                        countries.map((country) => {
                            console.log(country.flag)
                            return <CardComponent key={country.name} 
                                        title={country.name} 
                                        image={country.flag}
                                        population={country.population} 
                                        region={country.region} 
                                        capital={country.capital}/>
                        })
                    )}
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home;



import React from 'react';
import {ReactSVG} from 'react-svg';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';


const CardComponent = (props) => {
    const { title, flag, population, region, capital } = props;


    return (
        <Card>
            <ReactSVG src={flag}/>            
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{title}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>Population: <span id="Population">{population}</span><br></br></Card.Text>                    
                <Card.Text>Region: <span id="Region">{region}</span><br></br></Card.Text>
                <Card.Text>Capital: <span id="Capital">{capital}</span><br></br></Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default CardComponent;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here is also a link to my Git repo for this project https://github.com/codejohnson89/react-countries

Comment: you typed **flag** to the **image**. so you have to use **image** variable in **CardComponent**. Please check the below answer.

Comment: @Boris thank you! I knew something silly like this would hold me up. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: no worries, if it helps you, please vote up my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is some error. Please check this code.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import CardComponent from '../components/Card';

const baseURL = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all';

const Home = () => {
    const [ countries, setCountries ] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('hello')
        axios.get(baseURL).then((res) => {
            setCountries(res.data);
        })
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    {countries && (
                        countries.map((country) => {
                            console.log(country.flag)
                            return <CardComponent key={country.name} 
                                        title={country.name} 
                                        image={country.flag}
                                        population={country.population} 
                                        region={country.region} 
                                        capital={country.capital}/>
                        })
                    )}
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home;



import React from 'react';
import {ReactSVG} from 'react-svg';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';


const CardComponent = (props) => {
    const { title, image, population, region, capital } = props;


    return (
        <Card>
            <img src={image} alt="title" width="80"/>            
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{title}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>Population: <span id="Population">{population}</span><br></br></Card.Text>                    
                <Card.Text>Region: <span id="Region">{region}</span><br></br></Card.Text>
                <Card.Text>Capital: <span id="Capital">{capital}</span><br></br></Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default CardComponent;
```